# how to Unhighlight the tabbaritem

Tags: iphone

I have three TabBarItem in a TabBar . In one case, i want to remove the TabBarItem selection from any of the three TabBarItems . i.e., the complete TabBar will not show any TabBarItems selected. Can i achieve it?

Kindly help me regarding on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**No.**  While this may be technically possible, it is likely a violation of Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.  If a tab bar is on display, the current view's tab should be highlighted.  What does the tab bar represent in your app?  If it's not used to switch between views, consider employing a [`UISegmentedControl`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

yes Justin's right.When you think about it showing none of the tab bar items as selected doesn't make any sense.