# unhighlight uitabbaritem in uitabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I have UITabBarController having 5 tabbar buttons. On some activity I want to unhighlight all the tab bat items.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you,

Ankita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to say that unselecting all tabbaritems is a bad user experience. Chances are high that it won't be accepted into the appstore.

After I said that, I found the answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952287/uitabbarcontroller-how-to-make-no-tabs-selected-at-start-up). You can accept this answer (if it works!!!) but props should be given to that user. He used a trick in Key Value Observing, and used the following code:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {     
    // Create the view controller which will be displayed after application startup     
    mHomeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];      
    [tabBarController.view addSubview:mHomeViewController.view];     
    tabBarController.delegate = self;     
    [tabBarController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedViewController" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];      
    // further initialization ... 
}  

// This method detects if user taps on one of the tabs and removes our "Home" view controller from the screen. 
- (BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {     
    if (!mAllowSelectTab)     
    {         
        [mHomeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];         
        mAllowSelectTab = YES;     
    }      
    return YES; 
}  

// Here we detect if UITabBarController wants to select one of the tabs and set back to unselected. 
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {     
   if (!mAllowSelectTab)     
    {         
        if (object == tabBarController && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectedViewController"])         
        {             
            NSNumber *changeKind = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeKindKey];              
            if ([changeKind intValue] == NSKeyValueChangeSetting)             
            {                 
                NSObject *newValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];                  
                if ([newValue class] != [NSNull class])                 
                {                     
                    tabBarController.selectedViewController = nil;                 
                }             
            }         
        }     
    } 
}
```

He added the following note:

> the first view controller from tabbar
>   still will be loaded (although for a
>   very short time), so its viewDidLoad
>   and viewWillAppear will be called
>   after startup. You may want to add
>   some logic to prevent some
>   initializations you probably may do in
>   these functions until "real" display
>   of that controller as a result of user
>   tap (using for example global
>   variables or NSNotificationCenter).

EDIT: this is for adapting the Apple-UITabbar. You can also create a custom UITabbar.

Comment: @Joetjah: I don't want to disable the button. I just want to unhighlight it.

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: I actually found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467568/how-to-unhighlight-the-tabbaritem   As stated in the answer there, I'd recommend using a UISegmentedControl. This way, you can set the `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` to any value.

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: Actually, I'm editting my answer to answer your question. I found something...

Comment: @Joetjah: Thanks for your answer but If I set this tabController.selectedViewController = nil; no tabs are selected but I just want to unhighlight the tab

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: In that case, I don't get the difference? What is the difference between unhighlighting and unselecting?

Comment: @Joetjah: unhighlight just means removing the highlight without doing any other operation of loading or uploading the viewcontroller. Just that highlighted part should be removed

Comment: @Joetjah: You can check out the app iMobsters which is doing exact the same.

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: In that case, I do believe unhighlighting is impossible, and the closest you can get to it is by hightlighting.. nothing. Changing focus in controllers usually means calling other methods. This goes for the standard, Apple-tabbar only! You can also create a custom UITabBar. In that case, you should program the highlight options yourself.

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: And what I've seen from iMobster, is a custom tabbar indeed. You can program the event that occurs when clicking a barbutton yourself.

Comment: @Joetjah: Thanks for your comments so do you have any example of custom tab bar with these options that i can refer to solve this issue?

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: For creating a custom tab bar (button): http://wn.com/iPhone_SDK_Tutorial_Custom_Tab_Bar In here, you should just create two icons per tabbarbutton: one for selected, one for not selected. If you want, you can keep the same picture for both states. Therefore, it will look like it didn't change.

Comment: @Joetjah: I'm sorry for being trouble, but your example just sets the background for tabbar, nothing else :(

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: No problem at all; I'm at work and incredibly bored, haha! Check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501363/iphone-uitabbar-custom-image-doesnt-work It (including the answer, ofcourse) explains how he or she created a tabbar button with a custom image.